# How to double-click a file to perform a number of CMD commands on it (using "Open With...")?

Tags: variables, command, cmd, directory, filenames

- I have a set of files with a common file extension, e.g. *.EXT.
- These files are located in different folders on my PC.
- I have a cmd script "Script.bat", located in C:/foo/ folder

I've set an "Open with..." file association for the *.EXT files to be opened by this "Script.bat" CMD script.

The questions is:

- which variable do I have to use to designate **the filename** and the **location** of the doubleclicked EXT file within the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The associated application, in your case your batch file, will be called with the "double clicked" file as the first command line argument. Thus, the fully qualified filename to that file (including the "location") will be available in `%1`.

Example (sort of):

```
 @echo off
 REM assuming this is your "Script.bat"
 echo You double clicked on "%~1"
```

Note that using `%~1` instead of simply `%1` removes enclosing quotes, which have been automatically added by Windows when it called your application (batch file).

For example, Windows will call it like you would have entered it in `CMD.EXE` like this:

```
 Script.bat "C:\Wherever it is\file.ext"
```

To extract individual parts you have a couple of options:

```
 echo Filename only: %~n1
 echo Filename and extension: %~nx1
 echo Drive and directory only: %~dp1
```

For a complete list of possibilities enter `FOR /?` on the prompt and page all the way to the end (mentally replace "%I" by "%1" for your example).

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out. I'm shamed of forgetting such basics:)